# naming of sections in Rnw script in rstudio

Tags: label, rstudio, rnw

In standard R scripts, sections can be labelled by adding four dashes after a comment. E.g.

```
# simple math ----
1+1
```

looks like this:

[image: script with label]

how can I label sections in a `Rnw` script? Four dashes don't work here. See:

[image: script without label]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be the following one:

```
<<section-label-name>>=
//code
@
```

Regards,

J_F

Comment: I don't mean labelling chunks of code. I mean the function within RStudio. In the first image it says "simple math" as intended, in the second it doesn't. It just says "c (Top Level)"

Comment: I don´t get the point. With my solution this is possible. Of course it´s named "chunk" but the usage is the same: You can jump between the sections, etc.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is a way, but not what I am looking for, because I do not want do add a chunk without needing one. So I am actually looking for a way that comments serve as labels. Thanks for clarifying.